# UILabel height inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a tableview where the height of the cells are dynamic.

So far I manage to set the height of the cells depending on the custom UILabel I've added inside.

With the regular cell.textLabel it works fine, but when I use my own label something goes wrong. I only see half the label, but when I scroll up and down, sometimes the label extends and shows all the text... You can see where the label should end in the image.

[Image](http://cl.ly/image/1e373o173C1B)

This is the text inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell.
Car *carForCell = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
nameLabel.text = carForCell.directions;
[nameLabel sizeToFit];

[nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];


return cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have typos in the code you posted, you don't seem to be adding the label to the cell at all. You also seem to be creating a new label every time, and then replacing the contents of your `nameLabel` pointer with the cell's view (which will always be nil).

Try doing something like this first and then see how it looks:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UILabel *nameLabel;

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    nameLabel.tag = 100;

    nameLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [nameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:nameLabel];
}
else {
     nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
}

// Configure the cell.
Car *carForCell = [cars objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

nameLabel.text = carForCell.directions;
[nameLabel sizeToFit];

return cell;
```

You will also need to tell the tableView what size each cell needs to be using the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method. That will mean getting the relevant `Car` object again and calculating the height using `sizeWithFont:sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:`

Comment: I already set the height of the cell in the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath` method, as you can see in the image. I changed the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and this was the result: [link](http://cl.ly/image/063e3Y0N2E05). All text is prited out, but the width seems to be messed up.

Comment: I think this is a problem with `sizeToFit:` - can you calculate the label size using `sizeWithFont:sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` ?

Comment: Seems to be working. I'll try it out some more before marking this the right answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the height of the cell? It should be done in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: I set the height in `heightForRowAtIndexPath `, already and it works perfect. The problem is the label that won't stretch, it just cuts of in the middle of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate and return the height of the UITableViewCell in the following method:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Here you should do your initial calculation of how high your cell should be.

For example:

```
CGSize textSize = [myString sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(320, 9999)];
return textSize.height;
```